# Hook is not being called on "post_system" event in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need to add the ability to track user actions by storing in a DB the IP address, the logged in user information and the action itself which is the URL the user is accessing. I would like to store also which parameters are being sent to the backend (POST|GET) if it's possible.

I don't like to reinvent the wheel so I took some time to perform a Google search and this [ci-usertracking](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ci-usertracking/) shows up. It's really old, it says it only has been tested from 1.6.3 to 1.7.1 (weird 1.7.0 is being skipped because of a bug).

I am using CI 2.1.3 (yessssss: outdated not the last version on the 2.x branch but is what we have in this legacy project and I don't want to update it to a newest version because I can cause caos lol).

This is what I have done so far (after download the files and unpack them :) ):

- Copy the files to it's respective folders and setup them as follow
- Create the table on the DB (SQL Server)

```php
//application/config/usertracking_config.php
$config['usertracking']['user_identifier']       = null;
$config['usertracking']['auto_track']            = true;
$config['usertracking']['tracking_filter'][]     = null;
$config['usertracking']['tracking_filter_logic'] = 'OR';
$config['usertracking']['auto_build_db']         = false;
$config['usertracking']['auto_fix_db']           = false;

// application/config/autoload.php
$autoload['libraries'] = array('Template', 'database', 'session', 'Ion_auth', 'Usertracking');

// application/hooks/hooks.php
$hook['post_system'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'Usertracking',
    'function' => 'auto_track',
    'filename' => 'Usertracking.php',
    'filepath' => 'libraries'
);
```

I am debugging the application using Xdebug and I am able to see the `Usertracking` class constructor being called but for some reason the function `auto_track()` is not called and therefore nothing is happening meaning nothing is being written to the DB.

Here is the code for the `Usertracking` class (apologies since it's large):

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

/**
 * User Tracking for CodeIgniter
 *
 * A library for tracking user activity in CodeIgniter applications.
 * Requires PHP v.5.1 or higher.
 *
 * @package        Usertracking for CodeIgniter
 * @author         Casey McLaughlin
 * @copyright      Open Source BSD License
 * @license        http://caseyamcl.com/resources/userTrackingForCI#license
 * @link           http://caseyamcl.com/resources/userTrackingForCI#license
 * @since          Version 1.2
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Usertracking library
 *
 * @package          Usertracking for CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage       Libraries
 * @author           Casey McLaughlin
 * @link             http://caseyamcl.com/resources/userTrackingForCI#license
 */
class Usertracking
{
    private $CI;
    private $configuration;

    private $needed_fields = array(
        array(
            'name'                 => 'id',
            'type'                 => 'int',
            'primary_key'          => 1,
            'forge_type'           => 'int',
            'forge_auto_increment' => true
        ),
        array('name' => 'session_id', 'type' => 'string', 'forge_type' => 'varchar', 'forge_constraint' => '100'),
        array('name' => 'user_identifier', 'type' => 'string', 'forge_type' => 'varchar', 'forge_constraint' => '255'),
        array('name' => 'request_uri', 'type' => 'string', 'forge_type' => 'text'),
        array('name' => 'timestamp', 'type' => 'string', 'forge_type' => 'varchar', 'forge_constraint' => '20'),
        array('name' => 'client_ip', 'type' => 'string', 'forge_type' => 'varchar', 'forge_constraint' => '50'),
        array('name' => 'client_user_agent', 'type' => 'string', 'forge_type' => 'text'),
        array('name' => 'referer_page', 'type' => 'string', 'forge_type' => 'text')
    );

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Does nothing but run the initialization
     * method.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void|boolean Will return FALSE if the intialization did not succeed.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //connect to CodeIgnitor
        if (!$this->CI =& get_instance()) {
            echo 'The UserTracking library is built for CodeIgnitor 1.6.3 and cannot be used outside of CI.';
            exit();
        }

        $this->initialize();
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Initialization script
     *
     * Checks the environment to ensure that the library
     * will run.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return boolean The result of the intialization process
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        //if php is not new enough, show error and die.
        if (PHP_VERSION < 5.1) {
            show_error('The Usertracking plugin is supported only on PHP v5.1 and above!');

            return false;
        }

        //check for the configuration file
        if (!$this->CI->config->load('usertracking_config') OR $this->CI->config->item('usertracking') === false) {
            show_error('Missing the configuration for UserTracking.  Ensure you have installed UserTracking correctly.');

            return false;
        }

        //Load the configuration
        $this->configuration = $this->CI->config->item('usertracking');

        //check the database for the table
        if (!$this->check_database()) {
            show_error('The database is not setup correctly for UserTracking.  Check to ensure proper database setup, or check the config settings for usertracking.');

            return false;
        }

        //if made it here
        return true;
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Automatically Track User Events
     *
     * Auto-track is meant to be run only from a CodeIgniter hook.  It
     * checks to ensure that autotracking is enabled, checks any filters
     * that may have been configured in the configuration file, and then
     * runs the {@link trackThis()} method.
     *
     * @return boolean The result of the tracking action (whether a db record was added or not)
     */
    public function auto_track()
    {
        //check the conditions
        if ($this->configuration['auto_track'] === true) {
            $proceed = $this->check_filters();

            if ($proceed === true) {
                return $this->track_this();
            }
        }
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Track the current pageview
     *
     * Retrieves information from the session, user agent, and server
     * fields, and then adds a record to the tracking database.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return boolean The result of the tracking action (whether a db record was added or not)
     */
    public function track_this()
    {
        //load necessary libraries
        $this->CI->load->database();
        $this->CI->load->library('user_agent');
        $this->CI->load->library('session');

        //get the data
        $input_data                      = array();
        $input_data['session_id']        = $this->CI->session->userdata('session_id');
        $input_data['request_uri']       = $this->CI->input->server('REQUEST_URI');
        $input_data['timestamp']         = time();
        $input_data['client_ip']         = $this->CI->input->server('REMOTE_ADDR');
        $input_data['client_user_agent'] = $this->CI->agent->agent_string();
        $input_data['referer_page']      = $this->CI->agent->referrer();

        //Get the user identifier, if set
        if ($this->configuration['user_identifier'] !== null && is_array($this->configuration['user_identifier'])) {
            if (count($this->configuration['user_identifier']) === 3) {
                list($class_type, $class_name, $function_name) = $this->configuration['user_identifier'];
                $the_args = array();
            } elseif (count($this->configuration['user_identifier']) === 4) {
                list($class_type, $class_name, $function_name, $the_args) = $this->configuration['user_identifier'];
            }

            if (!$this->CI->load->$class_type($class_name)) {
                if ((($class_type !== 'helper') &&
                        !method_exists($this->CI->$class_name,
                                       $function_name)) OR ($class_type === 'helper' && !function_exists($function_name))) {
                    show_error("Could not load the $function_name in $class_name.  Check the userIdentifier configuration in userTracking config. User Identifier will not be tracked.");
                } else //Do it!
                {
                    if ($class_type === 'helper') {
                        $input_data['user_identifier'] = call_user_func_array($function_name, $the_args);
                    } else {
                        $input_data['user_identifier'] = call_user_func_array(
                            array(
                                $this->CI->$class_name,
                                $function_name
                            ),
                            $the_args
                        );
                    }
                }
            } else {
                show_error("Could not load the $class_type: $class_name.  Check the userIdentifier configuration in userTracking config. User Identifier will not be tracked.");
            }
        }

        //Add it to the database
        $this->CI->load->database();
        $result = $this->CI->db->insert('usertracking', $input_data);

        if ($result === false) {
            show_error('Could not write to the usertracking table in the database while trying to add a tracking record.  Double-check configureation and datbase setup for Usertracking library!');
        }

        //Return the database write result
        return $result;
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Check/Process filters
     *
     * This is run as part of the autoTrack() function.  It processes any
     * filters defined in the configuration file and returns either TRUE or FALSE.
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return boolean Whether or not the filter tests suceeded.
     */
    private function check_filters()
    {
        //Get the tracking filters from the config
        $tracking_filters = $this->configuration['tracking_filter'];

        //If there are filters, process them
        if (is_array($tracking_filters) && count($tracking_filters) > 0 && $tracking_filters[0] !== null) {
            $filter_results = array();

            //go through each tracking filter and make sure that they pass
            foreach ($tracking_filters as $curr_filter) {
                //Check the filter for the right type
                if (!is_array($curr_filter) OR (count($curr_filter) !== 4 && count($curr_filter) !== 5)) {
                    show_error("The userTracking filter is malformed.  Check the userTracking configuration.  Filter: $curr_filter");
                    continue;
                }

                if (count($curr_filter) === 4) {
                    list($class_type, $class_name, $function_name, $expected_result) = $curr_filter;
                    $the_args = array();  //This is empty
                } elseif (count($curr_filter) === 5) {
                    list($class_type, $class_name, $function_name, $expected_result, $the_args) = $curr_filter;
                } else {
                    show_error("The userTracking filter is malformed.  Check the userTracking configuration.  Filter: $curr_filter");
                    continue;
                }

                //Run the filter
                if (!$this->CI->load->$class_type($class_name)) {
                    if ((($class_type !== 'helper') &&
                            !method_exists($this->CI->$class_name,
                                           $function_name)) OR ($class_type === 'helper' && !function_exists($function_name))) {
                        show_error("Could not load the $function_name in $class_name.  The filter will not be applied.");
                    } else //Do it!
                    {
                        if ($class_type === 'helper') {
                            $curr_filter_result = call_user_func_array($function_name, $the_args);
                        } else {
                            $curr_filter_result = call_user_func_array(array($this->CI->$class_name, $function_name),
                                                                       $the_args);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    show_error("Could not load the $class_type: $class_name.  Check the userIdentifier configuration in userTracking config. User filter will not be applied.");
                }

                //Analyze the results
                //If there is no result for the current filter, autofail!
                if (!isset($curr_filter_result)) {
                    $filter_results[] = 'fail';
                } else //if there is a result, test it
                {
                    //Do a strong type comparison if we are expecting true or false
                    if ($expected_result === true OR $expected_result === false) {
                        if ($curr_filter_result === $expected_result) {
                            $filter_results[] = 'pass';
                        } else {
                            $filter_results[] = 'fail';
                        }
                    } else //Do a weak type comparison for everything else
                    {
                        if ($curr_filter_result == $expected_result) {
                            $filter_results[] = 'pass';
                        } else {
                            $filter_results[] = 'fail';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //check the results
            if (strtoupper($this->configuration['tracking_filter_logic']) === 'AND') //AND Logic
            {
                if (!in_array('fail', $filter_results, false)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else //OR Logic
            {
                if (in_array('pass', $filter_results, false)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else //no filters to check -- pass automatically.
        {
            return true;
        }
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Check Database
     *
     * This checks and, if defined in the configuration file, builds the
     * necessary database tables for tracking using the CI database forge class.
     *
     * If it finds a malformed table, it will backup that table and create a new one.
     *
     * @access private
     * @return boolean Whether the database table exists or was setup succesfully.
     */
    private function check_database()
    {
        //load the ci database and db forge classes, or show error & return FALSE
        $this->CI->load->database();
        $this->CI->load->dbforge();

        //check to see if the table exists
        if ($this->CI->db->table_exists('usertracking')) {
            //if the table exists, check to see if the columns are setup correctly
            $fields = $this->CI->db->field_data('usertracking');

            //if the columns are setup correctly, return TRUE
            $num_matched = 0;
            foreach ($this->needed_fields as $needed_field) {
                $nf_name = $needed_field['name'];
                $nf_type = $needed_field['type'];

                foreach ($fields as $the_field) {
                    if ($the_field->name == $nf_name && $the_field->type = $nf_type) {
                        $num_matched++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($num_matched < count($this->needed_fields) && $this->configuration['auto_fix_db'] === true) {
                //if the columns are setup incorrectly and autofix_db is on, fix the db and return TRUE

                //rename the table
                global $CI;
                $db_prefix = $CI->db->dbprefix;
                $this->CI->dbforge->rename_table($db_prefix . 'usertracking', 'usertracking_backup_' . time());
                $this->CI->db->query('UNLOCK TABLES;');

                //rebuild the table
                $result = $this->build_database_table();

                //return TRUE
                return $result;
            } elseif ($this->configuration['auto_fix_db'] !== true && $num_matched < count($this->needed_fields)) {
                //if the columns are setup incorrectly and autofix_db is off, show error return FALSE
                show_error('The database table exists, but is malformed and not setup correctly.');

                return false;
            } else //everything is setup right
            {
                return true;
            }
        } elseif ($this->configuration['auto_build_db'] === true) {
            //if the table doesn't exist, and autoBuild_db is on, build the table and return TRUE
            $result = $this->build_database_table();

            return $result;
        } else {
            //if the table doesn't exist, and autoBuild_db is off, show error and return FALSE
            show_error('The usertracking database table does not exist.  Check your database installation.');

            return false;
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Build Database Table
     *
     * Builds the database table.  If one already exists, it will overwrite.  This method
     * should only be called from the {@link checkDatabase} method to avoid potential
     * data loss.
     *
     * @access private
     * @return boolean Whether the table was built succesfully
     */
    private function build_database_table()
    {
        //load the ci database and db forge classes, or show error & return FALSE (if not already done)
        $this->CI->load->database();
        $this->CI->load->dbforge();

        //create a new table with the appropriate fields
        $new_fields = array();

        foreach ($this->needed_fields as $curr_nf) {
            $name              = $curr_nf['name'];
            $new_fields[$name] = array('type' => $curr_nf['forge_type']);
            if (isset($curr_nf['forge_constraint'])) {
                $new_fields[$name]['constraint'] = $curr_nf['forge_constraint'];
            }
            if (isset($curr_nf['forge_auto_increment'])) {
                $new_fields[$name]['auto_increment'] = $curr_nf['forge_auto_increment'];
            }

            if (isset($curr_nf['primary_key']) && $curr_nf['primary_key'] === 1) {
                $this->CI->dbforge->add_key($name, true);
            }
        }

        $this->CI->dbforge->add_field($new_fields);
        $this->CI->dbforge->create_table('usertracking');

        return true;
    }
}
```

Maybe this is a miss configuration or something else  but I can't find where the problem is. Can any give me some ideas or maybe recommend me a better library for this purpose?

Comment: Can you add the code for the `Usertracking` class?

Comment: @DFriend done, check the updated OP

Comment: `$this->initialize();` returns `TRUE`? You should probably be checking its return in `__construct()`.

Comment: @DFriend why? I can move what is on `$this->initialize();` to the constructor but why do I need to check it's return?

Comment: Because it sets up a number of things that MUST succeed or the class won't function properly. Doesn't really explain why the `auto_track` method isn't called. But still important.

Comment: Try removing 'Usertracking' from autoload.php - the hook will load it.

Comment: Well I can do the check while still not clear to me why but if I am not wrong a PHP constructor can not return any value, instead it could throw a few Exceptions. So what I can do is convert each `false` return to a `RuntimeException`. Having said that, I made the changes you mention before and the ones I mention here but still not working, I am not seeing any being logged or any other error at all. Because `user_identifier` need some configuration I would expect to see an error at least but that isn't happening either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163060/discussion-between-dfriend-and-reynierpm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a hook isn't called there could be a couple reasons.

The hooks config file (hooks.php) might not be configured correctly.
Or, in your case, it is where you hooks.php is stored.

You show it as being at

*/application/**hooks**/hooks.php*

but it should be at

*/application/**config**/hooks.php*.

The directory `/application/hooks/` was designed as the place to store files that hook.php loads. But that's not a must-do as long as the config values are right. And yours is if `Usertracking.php` is in `application/libraries`.

There is another reason that a hook does not run. If somewhere in the controller (or classes the controller uses i.e. model, libraries, etc) there is a call to `exit` or `die`. Either of those PHP methods will short-circuit the framework's designed execution path. The result could mean that multiple hook points will never be evaluated.